# How to observe MPMoviePlayerController according to the playback time?

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, avfoundation, key-value-observing

In order to invoke some events for the specified time, for example, when the video goes to 10.0s, or 20.0s , there should be some events to be invoked, is that possible to observe some property of the instance of MPMoviePlayerController for such cases ? Or any other solutions ?

Answer (score 0):

I had to do almost the same thing and I didn't find any good solution except by using my own NSTimer and look at some moments the current time of the MPMoviePlayer...

So basically, every seconds I'm watching what current time it is and when I'm interrested in the time, I do my stuff.

Comment: yes, I am doing with the same approach, but that is not so pretty I think. That is why question here for possible perfect solution.

Comment: I do agree with you (that's not pretty at all) and I'll keep this thread in my mind to know more about this. Good luck !

Comment: There is no other solution. `currentPlaybackTime` is not KVO compliant.

Comment: Is that feasible to use category and AVPlayer to make currentPlaybackTime KVO compliant ?